# My MPLAB X IDE debugger gives me an error whenever I try to debug my PIC24 Explorer 16/32 Development Board

Tags: pic, debugging, mplabx

I am doing a simple program for my [PIC24FJ1024GB610](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC24FJ1024GB610) microcontroller from Microchip, using the [Explorer 16/32 Development Board](http://www.microchip.com/developmenttools/ProductDetails/DM240001-3), it has it's own PKOB (PICkit On Board circuitry).

My IDE is: [MPLAB X IDE v5.05](https://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide)
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64 bits,

Whenever I try to download my program into the development board, I get this error:

> The programmer could not be started: Could not connect to tool hardware: PKOBSKDEPlatformTool, com.microchip.mplab.mdcore.pkobskde.PKOBSKDEDbgToolManager

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: According to [this Microchip forum thread](https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000MeLEEA0/t385127) performing a 'Reset' could work.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your XC16/32 compiler is up-to-date. Then disconnect your PIM from the board. Then plug in your micro-B USB connector into J18. The PKOB enumerates as a HID class so there should be no drivers needed.

Do you see the following inside MPLABX?

[image]

I've also found that sometimes this error can occur if the power supply is insufficient. Consider plugging in the barrel connector at J12.

See the [official docs](http://microchipdeveloper.com/boards:explorer1632) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My X16 C compiler is up to date, and it is the same as the one in the website MPLAB X16 C Compiler v1.35. Yes I see the Explorer 16/32 hardware tool whenever I create a new project. But I still get the same problem

Comment: Try loading the IPE instead of MPLABX to program. Compile inside MPLABX and load the hex inside the IPE. Failing that, install the latest version of the JRE and reinstall MPLABX.

Comment: I will try writing the program using IPE, I didnt have this problem with earlier versions of MPLAB X IDE. I will try the solutions provided and see what will happen.

Comment: I uninstalled MPLAB X IDE v5.05, then installed it again, I could program the microcontroller (download the code into the micro), but when I try to debug it, it gives me the same error. Earlier versions of MPLAB X IDE didn't give me that error, I will try to install an older version, maybe it will work